# Why are black people referred to as "colored people"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

When someone calls a black person "a colored guy", I can't help but think about the question "are white people colorless? Isn't white a color too?"

Comment: At one time using "colored" was actually considered more polite than using "black".  This is one reason why the NAACP has that name.

Comment: Note that in some countries, "colored person" has a specific meaning that is distinctly different to "black person": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_groups_in_South_Africa#Coloured_South_Africans

Comment: "are white people colorless? Isn't white a color too?" – If you really are into nitpicking about calling black people colored, then the fact that white is not a color but a mix of all colors is much less interesting than the fact that black is literally the *absence of color*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag only with light: not with pigments. It’s the other way round for pigments.

Comment: Why are black people called that, when few, if any, "black" people are actually black? They're various shades of brown.

Comment: @Tim pigments only have visible color because light shines on them and they reflect some of it and absorb others. A white pigment appears white because a white light shines on it and all is reflected. Without light there is no color; our eyes react to the presence of light, not the presence of pigments, so light is the only thing that matters

Comment: @jamesqf ...and in some places, if people are actually paler than I am, and of their 16 great-great-grandparents 15 were European and one was brown, they are still officially "black".

Comment: @jamesqf I was surprised about that too, until I met people from the Congo and Uganda.

Comment: @ Mast: Still really dark brown :-)  Indeed, the darkest people I've ever met personally were from southern India.  What I'm saying is that language is not rational, and laws sometimes even less so.

Comment: It's the same reason that people think they have no accent, and that only others, with different accents, have an accent. We are "normal", expected, uncolored, unaccented. They are odd, colored, accented. And this is amplified and reinforced when "we" is the dominant group in a culture or is the dominant culture.

Comment: The use of the term *color**ed*** in this question has distracted, and will keep distracting, those who visit this page, because that term is nowadays not widely used, and is regarded by many people as problematic because of its historical associations. The OP could have, however, asked essentially the same question about the term *of color*, which is perceived as free of the historical associations that burden the term *colored*.

Comment: FWIW, re terminology look at a sheet of printer paper:  it's white.  Now look at a "white" person.  Same color?  I see various shades of a kind of pinkish tan.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : No.  White, gray, and black are achromatic.  Lightness and hue are orthogonal properties of color.  This is fairly straightforwardly expressed in the [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color spaces.

Comment: @Eric, this is true _only_ with a defined white reference; every color space has one. 'Color' is by definition perception of light, and white is no different. _Everything_ we see has color, except for pure black. What 'objectively' exists is only spectrum, and as it turns out, the spectrum of the black (human :) body and white body is remarkably similar: just different lightness (with ref, from memory, to [Mark Changizi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Changizi)).

Comment: @HotLicks In some places, it is so now.

Comment: Maybe "swarthy" could be the new black (pun intended) for a polictically correct term meaning "dark skinned"

Comment: @jamesqf This is all about the degree of fundamental pigmentation (that is the amount of permanent melanin in the skin). "White" people have very little of it in general but the term 'coloured person'  doesn't just include people of African heritage it also includes people of South Asian, East Asian (who have little more permanent melanin than a European), Polynesian and Native American heritage as well as the Apartheid Era South African term "Cape Coloured" which was a term for people of mixed race. S Africa has got past that but other places still make these ridiculous, evil distinctions.

Comment: Be aware that these terms are very culture dependent, and I won't just mean black v white culture. British black people have a different idea of what is acceptable and polite than American black people.

Comment: @BoldBen - I would not say that South Africa has actually gotten past that. There is still a distinct racial divide. It just isn’t legislated any longer. Though, you find South Africans living in the Americas, Europe, and Australia more open and accepting. And, you find Individuals in South Africa more open in their personal relations. There is still a very pervasive divide in cultural inclusion between blacks, whites, Indians, coloureds, Muslims (of any race), etc. Most of it now stems from economic disparity.

Comment: @BoldBen: Not in general US usage, at least. "Colored people" are ONLY those of sub-Saharan African ancestry.  Nor are such terms "evil" or ridiculous in themselves, they're just descriptions, not fundamentally different from describing my dog as a brindle Plott Hound (mostly, anyway), or my horses as a roan mustang and a bay Anglo-Arab.

Comment: @DeanF. I didn't mean that they'd solved all their racially based problems, that's obviously not true, but what has gone is the complex structure of Apartheid which applied legal classifications to people on not just racial but ethnic origins. A good example of the type of knots the white minority got themselves into  at that time was the banning of the popular Jeremy Taylor song [Ag Pleez Deddy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ag_Pleez_Deddy) from radio playlists because it contains both English and Afrikaans words and so was considered by radio execs to be against Apartheid principles.

Comment: @jamesqf It's not the terms which are evil and ridculous, it's the division of society based on racial origin which uses the terms to impose legal restrictions on a section of the population which is evil and ridiculous. The real problem is that the laws and the attitudes of the people forming, supporting and enforcing those laws run up against the infinite complexity of human genetics. I have about the same proportion of Neanderthal DNA as I have of the DNA from any one of my 18th century ancestors. Does that make me, and the white supremacists who share my ethnicity, Neanderthals?

Comment: @BoldBen: These days it's not the white supremacists, so much as it is those who claim some people are somehow "privileged", or should be entitled to special treatment, because of things that happened to long-ago ancestors.

Comment: @jamesqf In some ways I agree with you. Racism is a human condition, not an aspect of any particular ethnic group. However when a racial group is discriminated against to the point where members of that group die by police officers' actions after being stopped for comparatively minor infringements I think that members of that group have a point.

Comment: @BoldBen: We're getting astray from the question, but I think that police thing is a good example of what I meant by racism being used as an excuse.  Black cops shoot black people at about the same rate as white cops.  Black cops shoot white people for no justifiable reason, too.  (E.g. ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Justine_Damond https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Jeremy_Mardis )  But black people being killed becomes a racial issue, while white people being killed is just cops doing their thing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> "are white people colorless? Isn't white a color too?"

There is an interesting question at [Is there a word for "bright colored eyes"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539711/is-there-a-word-for-bright-colored-eyes) that is related.

The answer to that question is that the Farsi expression assumes that everyone has brown eyes.

Coloured" is used because the people who called other people "coloured" were British who, at that time were almost 100% "white". We can therefore understand that "coloured" is a subjective term. These subjective terms are quite common descriptives in languages.

It is not the fact that white people are "colourless", it is the fact that "coloured people have "a distinct and different colour".

The adjective "coloured" was fist used around 1400 to describe the complexion of a person:

**Definitions from the OED:**

**2. With modifying adverb. Having a complexion (of the specified kind).Recorded earliest in well-coloured adj.**

> a1400   tr. Lanfranc Sci. Cirurgie (Ashm.) (1894) 181 (MED)   *If þe pacient be fleischi & wel colourid.* *[if the patient is fat and has a good colour.]*

This is in current use:

> 1996   A. Weir "Children of Henry VIII" ii. viii. 189   *Mary, at thirty-seven, was small and thin, and her fresh-coloured face had been marred by years of anxiety and ill-health.*

In the mid-17th century, the world was divided into white, coloured, and black:

> **3 b. Denoting a member of any dark-skinned group of peoples, esp. a person of sub-Saharan African or (in Britain) South Asian origin or descent; in earliest use with reference to South America.**

(The reference to South America was probably because it had a very diverse population: see the 1794 quote in which the distinction between "coloured" and "black" is made.)

> 1758   J. Adams tr. A. de Ulloa Voy. S.-Amer. I. iii. iii. 123   *The Mestizo, or negro women, or the coloured women as they are called here [sc. Panama] [Sp. las Mugeres de colòr].*

> 1794   C. Bishop Let. 14 Dec. in Jrnl. & Lett. (1967) 23   *They Reckon the White inhabitants [of Rio de Janeiro] to be one forth of the whole,..the Coloured People one forth, and from twenty to thirty thousand Blacks.*

The OED notes:

> *Coloured was adopted in the United States by emancipated slaves as a term of racial pride after the end of the American Civil War. It was rapidly replaced from the late 1960s as a self-designation by black (see note at black adj. 3a) and later by African-American, although it is retained in the name of the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People.*

In Britain, "coloured" was the commoner term for Asian, or mixed-race people until the 1960s.

So we have a split in English:

> **3c. *Originally and chiefly U.S.* Of or belonging to any group of dark-skinned people, esp. African-Americans. Also, during the era of racial segregation in the United States: intended for or restricted to African-Americans. Now usually considered offensive.**

> 1821   Jrnl. Convent. Protestant Episcopal Church St. Paul's, Baltimore 21   *The Colored School, taught in the afternoon, has 12 teachers, and 150 scholars.*

In Britain, at that time. the term Black or Negro would have been used to refer to people of African descent (as in the 1821 quote), and "coloured" was restricted to those from British India or those of mixed race. e.g. A.C. Carmichael titled her 1841 book *"Domestic Manners and Social Condition of the White, Coloured and Negro Population of the West Indies"* It was not until much later - the late 20th entury, that the UK took up the term "coloured" to include anyone who was not white.

Comment: Apparently, [Australian autochthons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Australians#Terms_%22black%22_and_%22blackfella%22) also get called, or call themselves, “black”.

Comment: I knew a lady from Barbados living in New York City in the 1960s who was horrified and offended by the growing use of the term "Black" in reference to her family. She insisted that "Coloured" was the proper and preferred term. She grew up under British colonial rule.

Comment: @MTA: presumably she never had much luck getting them to accept that "u"!

Comment: *It is not the fact that white people are "colourless", it is the fact that "coloured people have "a distinct and different colour".* - white people come in all kinds of shades too. Caucasians can be white Norwegians all the way to Indians and even Africans from the horn of Africa.

Answer (score 20):

Some say that "colored" is neutral or in some cases even respectful, but it is hard to avoid the conclusion that the term is a racist distinction (cf. [Jim Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws)) and only ever meant "non-white." [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored):

> Colored, or coloured, is an ethnic descriptor historically used in the United States (predominantly during the Jim Crow era) and other European countries and their former colonies. In many of these places, it is now considered an ethnic slur.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws) Historically, the term denoted non-"white" individuals generally.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored) In contemporary English today, the term "people of colour" has become widespread and is considered more acceptable than coloured.

Example of drinking fountains (and labels of same) during the era of segregation:

[image: African-American man drinking from "colored" drinking fountain in the mid-20th century]

The distinction here is clearly to keep "colored" people from drinking at the "white" fountain.

It is worth noting, however, that at one time even organizations created and run by African-Americans used the term widely. Cf. the [NAACP](https://www.naacp.org/) (National Association for the Advancement of Colored People).

That said, these days it is advisable not to use that term yourself, especially if you are white.

Comment: In the US, the term PoC (People of Colour) is still used, although in the U.K., normally BaME is used.

Comment: @Tim what does 'BaME' stand for?

Comment: @Mitch Black And Minority Ethnic.

Comment: @Vicky - I believe it's [Black, Asian and minority ethnic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bame).

Comment: @Vicky, et al. That must be a UK phrasing. Does 'BaME' include Polish immigrants? Or is it really about skin color?

Comment: @Tim, but see https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-53194376 (which also addresses Mitch's question in part)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, but it’s still used on pretty much every official form or email, across government and industry. I’ll say that its very definitely a minority who are only recently objecting (and try and find a term which everyone agrees with!)

Comment: Is that photo from the US or South Africa?

Comment: @gerrit: From the US.

Comment: I would go farther and say its promulgation through Jim Crow laws is one of the reasons it is unacceptable today.

Comment: This is  the earliest use I've found so far (from 1800) - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_ZoLAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA469&dq=%22colored+people%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj668joq7nqAhXTT8AKHbcgDiI4wAIQ6AEwBHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22colored%20people%22&f=false -- Jim Crow (the minstrels) started in 1828

Comment: @Tim Of course, in the U.S., it's "of *Color*"  ;)

Comment: @Mitch: it varies. Sometimes it is about skin colour, sometimes it literally does mean any ethnic minority. For most statistical purposes in the UK, under "White" you'll see "British", "Irish", and "other white (please specify)" as options. Sometimes there are more break-downs of white. So in that sense Polish is an ethnic minority. There is some dispute whether this is improperly excluding British national minorities (such as Welsh) from consideration as ethnic minorities.

Comment: But, whether a given person saying "BAME" really means all minority ethnicities (including SE Asian, Roma, you name it), or really means "of African or South Asian descent" but wants to use a suitably official-sounding term, can vary a bit. Officially, though, yes, BAME does include Polish immigrants. Note also that for UK statistical purposes, someone's ethnicity is what they say it is. So for example if the child of Polish immigrants considers themselves "white British", they are.

Comment: Basically you've got at least three things going on though: who does the speaker intend to include, who does some official nomenclature say it includes, and who believes that choice of words is genuinely inclusive of them. It's a bit like LGBT+ in that sense: it's an open question whether there should there be more letters between T and + and, if so, which (LGBTQIA+ being the next most common version I've seen, but there are others).

Comment: This answer is culturally specific and should be labelled as such if you're going to say things like _"these days it is advisable not to use that term yourself, especially if you are white"_. Go to South Africa and see what happens. We don't all live in _your_ particular country!

Answer (score 11):

Terms like this are inherently problematic. If I describe my friend as "this kid with glasses and a lightning-shaped scar over his right eye," it's pretty clear that I'm describing objective identifying characteristics that are value-neutral, probably so you'll recognize him the next time you see him at Hogwarts.

Not so with words that describe race and nationality. The US has cycled through a lot of different terms for African-American people over the years. The words are pretty arbitrary in terms of their etymologies and literal meanings, so they're basically a random set of code-words. But what they code for is real and important. As an example, consider the following illustration, from an 1899 book by H. Strickland Constable (who I think was an upper-class Englishman):

[image]

Now in 1899, "negro" was actually a pretty respectful term for a posh Englishman to use for an African person -- more respectful than the term that was, for example, universally used by white people in Alabama. But the word comes laden with all kinds of values. It connotes  notions about race that we would now consider to be total pseudoscience (as in the caption of the figure). Because it was supposedly a biological term, it ignored the whole question of whether there ought to be a historical or cultural aspect to it, and it conflated African-Americans with Africans, who were completely different culturally.

A similar example is [this photo from 1965](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Barbara_Gittings_1965.jpg):

[image]

These people were sticking their necks out for an oppressed group, but the word "homosexuals" on the picket sign is jarring today, because it carries a connotation of being from that era, which was a time when gay people's sexual orientation was conceived of by most people as either immoral behavior or a mental illness. Likewise, I don't refer to my step-father as "oriental," which sounds like a word my grandmother could have used innocently, and carries the same pseudoscience connotations as "negro."

If you want a literally correct word for African-Americans, a good one logically would be "darkies," but that would be an awful social gaffe in today's America, because it sounds like something from Reconstruction. Actually what happened was that "negro" and "colored" gave way in the US in the 1960's to "black" or "Black," which connotes a different understanding. It emphasizes culture rather than ancestry, and in the capitalized form it indicated that Black people were thinking of themselves as an oppressed *nationality*, like the Irish. In the US, we also have "African-American" now, which emphasizes the analogy with other groups who came to this country.

Comment: "the term that was, for example, universally used by white people in Alabama" of course began its life as the word *negro.*  There are people even today who pronounce the words nearly identically.  I would also note that there is a phenomenon where a "polite" term is introduced as a euphemism for some impolite term, only to evolve into impolite term itself.  This can be seen in the terms relevant to the present question as well as with terms for "toilet" (itself originally a euphemism) in the US, and also in general with terms that describe women ("hussy," German *Weib,* Romance *puta).*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110311/discussion-between-computercarguy-and-steve-jessop).

Answer (score 10):

> "are white people colorless? Isn't white a color too?"

In scientific terms, white is not a single colour (i.e. a single wavelength of light). It is a combination of all visible colours. Some people describe white as a colour others don't. Of course "white" people aren't white at all. Their complexion varies according to health and exposure to the weather.

In 18th century Europe, a pale complexion was an indication of privilege. People who spent most of their time indoors were considered superior to those working in the fields. Note: I'm not talking about racial characteristics. I mean that "white Caucasians" who work in the sun get a tan.

This is true to the extent that white face-makeup was widely used to exaggerate the effect. Here's  an example.  I don't guarantee its total accuracy.
https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photos-th-century-vintage-make-up-girl-style-image40087763

Of course the opposite is now true. Pale-complexioned people see a dark skin as desirable and indicating privilege (it indicates you can afford a holiday in the sun). Hence the proliferation of tanning booths.

Comment: The part of this answer that directly responds to the OP's question is that 'in scientific terms, white is not a single colour'. But in the same scientific terms, black is not a colour either, so that doesn't explain why black people would be referred to as coloured, or of colour.

Comment: @jsw29 - So called 'black people' are in fact of varying shades of brown. Most people agree that brown is a colour.  Also, my point is that such vocabulary likely comes from a historical comparison with "white"

Comment: Indeed, but as you yourself say in the answer, white people are not actually white either. So, (1) if one goes by the actual colour, both white and black people are coloured, (2) if one goes by what they are called, and one interprets *coloured* in what you call 'scientific terms', then neither white nor black people are coloured, (3) if one goes by what they are called, and one interprets *coloured* in another way, then again both are. None of these ways of looking at the matter puts white and black people on the opposite sides.

Comment: @jsw29 - Okay, but if you expect the English language to be logical, you're probably asking too much.

Comment: Yes, **that** is the answer!

Comment: @jsw29 Indeed.  As far as I've seen, *every* attempt to justify any given racial term by logic fails.  This must be inevitable, since race itself is not a strictly logical concept, and skin color is only a part of it.  Whatever term one chooses will necessarily fail for certain cases.  We just have to accept that these terms don't fit perfectly, because they are useful nonetheless.  For the most part, when someone uses one of these terms, the meaning is clear.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Most people agree that brown is a colour." Not everyone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wh4aWZRtTwU

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: "Most people agree that brown is a colour" -- well, quite, but it is not "a single wavelength of light", which is why the stuff about pure wavelengths of light is totally irrelevant even to the definition of "colour" in relation to paint, let alone to people :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop - I take your point. However white is  combination of ***all*** visible wavelengths. All other colours (except pure black which is a complete absence of light) are a combination of ***some*** wavelengths, not all. In other words, each colour is white with some wavelengths removed. Newton worked this out with his prism experiment.  https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/mit-k12/mit-k12-science/mit-k12-physics/v/newtons-prism-experiment.

Comment: I still hold to the heraldic terminology that yellow isn't a colour, it's a metal. Newton can say what he likes ;-) In any case "white" still doesn't *always* mean "a combination of all visible wavelengths", since depending on the ratios some combinations of all wavelengths look white and others don't. Some things which are not a combination of all wavelengths look white and others don't (which is to do with colour reception in the eye).

Comment: @Steve Jessop - And to a blind person all colours look the same. I think this is far enough down the rabbit hole for me!

Answer (score 1):

George Carlin said it best :

https://www.c-span.org/video/?123268-1/brain-droppings
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx21zEdhlPQ

> “Now, if all of this begins to put you in mind of so-called politically correct language, or politically correct speech, then you and I are on the same track. So let's visit that playground of guilty white liberals, the land of the politically correct. In recent years, the P.C. folks have found some new ways of shading the truth in order to make people feel better — especially minorities. One of the newer phrases making the rounds is “happens to be”: “he happens to be black”. “I have a friend who happens to be black.” Oh I see, yes, yes... Like it's an accident, you know! “Happens to be black? – Yes, he happens to be black. – I see, I see, I see... he had two black parents? – Yes, that's right, two black parents. – I see... And they had sex? – Oh indeed they did. – I see... So where does the surprise part come in? I should think it would be more unusual if he just happened to be Scandinavian.” Another favorite term, recently favourite term, is “openly”: “openly gay”. “I have a friend who's openly gay.” But that's the only minority they use that for. You know, you wouldn't say someone was “openly black”... Well maybe James Brown... Or Louis Farrakhan — Louis Farrakhan is *openly black*. Colin Powell is not *openly black*; Colin powell is *openly white*; he just *happens to be black*. And while we're at it, when did the word “urban” become synonymous with the word “black”? Did I sleep through this perhaps? “Urban Styles”, “urban trends”, “urban music”... I was not consulted on this at all again, didn't get an e-mail, didn't get a fax, didn't get a postcard, that's fine, let them go. So, I would like to tell you how I handle some of these speech issues concerning minorities. First of all, I say “black”; I say “black” because most black people prefer “black”. I don't say “people of color” because it's dishonest; it means precisely the same thing as “colored people” which is an insult, so if you're not willing to say “colored people” you shouldn't be willing to say “people of color”. And besides, to me the whole idea of color seems a bit specious, really. I mean, what should we call white people? “People of no color”? Isn't pink a color? And in fact, white people are not really white at all, they're different shades of pink and olive and beige — in other words, they're colored. And black people are rarely black, I see mostly various shades of brown and tan, and in fact some light-skinned black people are lighter than the darkest white people. Look how dark the people in India are: they're dark brown, but they're considered white. May I see the color chart, please? “People of color” is an awkward phrase that obscures meaning rather than enhancing it. What shall we call fat people, “people of size”? I also don't say “African-Americans”, I find it cumbersome and confusing. Which part of Africa are we talking about? Egypt? Egypt is in Africa but Egyptians aren't black; they're like the people in India, they're dark brown white people. But they're Africans. So why wouldn't an Egyptian who becomes a US citizen be called an African-American? The same would apply to South Africa; suppose a white racist from South Africa becomes an American citizen, couldn't he call himself an African-American? If for no other reason than just to bother black people... And what about a black person born in South Africa who becomes an American citizen, is he an African-American or is he a South-African-American? Or is he simply a South-African-American-African-American? You know, it's just so much more tedious liberal labeling. Liberals should be taught that labels divide people, and I think we could probably do with fewer labels, not more.”

(The whole speech is a highly recommended listen, it's both brilliant and hilarious, as he was on stage, but with a more polite language geared toward a more high-brow audience. It contains an early version of his “Modern man” slam, later expanded and included in his 2005 comedy show “Life is worth losing”.)

Comment: I had to downvote for several reasons: 1. it's just a copy and paste job, original content is preferred on this site. 2. A wall of text always makes it more difficult to read. 3. The monologue doesn't answer the question. The comedian is in fact denouncing the hypocrisy and absurdity of language. 4. The only relevant bit is "*People of color” is an awkward phrase that obscures meaning rather than enhancing it.*" which is not an answer. I *adore* Carlin but his is an opinion piece, biased, in order to make laughs. Unsuitable as an an explanation as to why we (don't) say "colored"

Comment: The link would have been great as a comment on the OP, but yes, this is not an answer.

Comment: I really like how most people have upvoted Mari-Lou's downvote rationale, but left it at only two downvotes, so's not to overly discourage a new contributor. That's SO much nicer than seeing a ton of downvotes with no rationale given :) [Of course, could be the other seven people didn't have downvote privs yet, but I like the first possibility more.]

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, sorry... é_è DewyMorgan: Well, thanks, I guess... But I still think that it's relevant to the question, since the reason why this expression is used at all is in order to not offend (or to offend depending on who you ask). It's related to the notion of euphemistic language, and euphemism treadmill, which G. Carlin develops in an earlier segment of that speech (with his striking demonstration of how – and why – “shell shock” became “post-traumatic stress disorder”). What matters more and more is not using accurate language but using language as neutral (and dull) as possible.

Comment: Off-Topic: If you ask me PTSD is a far better, more accurate  descriptive expression than "shell shock" which originally referred to the effects that exploding artillery shells  had on a soldier's physical and psychological health.

Comment: A comedian's monologue isn't an academic answer to the question as asked (although could maybe be germane to how the words are thought of, among old White men).

Answer (score 0):

**“Why are black people referred to as “colored people?”**

**In the twenty-first century, the short answer is that they are not.**

The word “colored” when used to classify or categorize people is an anachronistic term dating back to before the Civil Rights Movement in the United States. It has not been in use as a socially acceptable term for over fifty years. Anyone under 70 Years old using the term today to refer to black people is looked upon (usually correctly) as racist. Anyone 70 or older using the term today is looked upon as ignorant or uncouth. Today the viewpoint on the term can be summed up in the words of African child-poet, Agra Gra in a poem dating back to the mid-1980’s that was nominated for best poem of 2006 by the U.N.

> **And You Call Me Colored**
> When I was born I was black
> When I was sad I was black
> When I was hot I was black
> When I was sick I was black
> When I was scared I was black
>
> When you was born you was pink
> When you was sad you was blue
> When you was hot you was red
> When you was sick you was green
> When you was scared you was yellow
>
> And you call me colored.

Categorizing a person based on their race is a very divisive and disruptive thing often used to create a dehumanizing effect in order to subjugate a class of people. “Colored” was a term to replace even more caustic terms in an effort of what we would term today as political correctness. Over time, the use of “colored“ was relegated to disuse for being socially unacceptable due to the fact that it was still used to separate and divide people to exclude them from the majority. Though, derivatives of its can still be found in some societies.

The term “people of color” is still used in the United States to denote anyone who is identified as not “white”. It is supposed to be a term of inclusion, uniting all racial ethnicities. It is still looked upon with some measure of controversy.

In South Africa, a coloured person is distinctly different than a black person. The term signifies a group of South Africans that come from multi-racial lineage. During the Apartheid Era, people from this group we’re considered their own separate race. Due to the segregation of Apartheid in all aspects of life including jobs, housing, politics, social interaction, and marriage, the children of mixed-raced lineage became genetically more and more distinct as their own distinct race generation after generation. Wikipedia states, “Genetic studies suggest the group has the highest levels of mixed ancestry in the world.“ Phenotypically, coloured (as they are called), especially cape-coloureds, display distinctive features that set them apart as unmistakable contrasted to whites, blacks, Indians, and other mixed-race individuals. Sort of a mix between African, Dutch, and French with some individuals throwing Malay into the mix.

Answer (score -1):

This link explains the origin of the phrase:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcG6bVkopIM

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).